# What power supply do I need to power these spotlights?

Tags: power-supply

I am thinking of using [these spotlights](http://shop.minispotlight.com/Mini-Barrel-Spotlight-MS01.htm) for a project.

My electrical knowledge is very rusty so please help. Each has a rating of 12 VDC and 30 mA. What rating do I need for the power supply if I were to use 10 of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding loads you **sum** the current requirements. The voltage stays the same because all your devices operate on the same voltage.

Thus, 10 times 30 mA = 300 mA.

You'll want a regulated 12V power supply that can provide at *least* 300 mA.

Comment: If hypothetically the voltage and amperage of the power supply were higher than what the parts need would the parts be burned out from overvoltage or over amperage?

Comment: Technically what does the "burning out" is amperage. The voltage is the "pressure" that causes over-current conditions. Think of it this way, if you connect a 12V 1A power supply to your ten devices, there will be 700mA "extra" that isn't needed, but available. However if the supply voltage were to increase to something that the devices aren't designed for, the excess voltage will cause the devices to take excess current, and burn them out.

Comment: @rabbid while jyelton is correct, sometimes the difference is slight enough that it doesn't matter. Especially if the spotlight is a simple LED + Resistor combo. A 13V or 14V might increase the current a few milliamps (35mA with 14V) while a lower voltage (10V or 11V) would decrease it (25mA with 10V). But there is a practical limit to the current the LED could support without affecting its lifespan or immediate burn out. And it's way easier to get a 12v supply in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

You can get a basic power supply circuit here http://embeddedbuzz.com/basic-electronics-design-first-power-supply/

just replace 7805 with 7812 for 12volt

Edit: This supply circuit will need other modifications to work well with the 7812 regulator. The linked design uses a 12V transformer, which is not suitable if the desire is to provide a well-regulated 12Vdc output. The transformer voltage should be higher than the desired supply voltage by (at least) the voltage drop across the bridge rectifier plus the worst-case drop out voltage of the regulator.

No need to add More than 12Volt Transformer ,A Large Capacitor more than 100uF Is Enough considering Ripple factor.

Comment: This is not a good answer. The supply you have linked to will need modifications if it is to work properly with a 7812 regulator.

Comment: @JoeHass Actually, a "12 Volt output transformer" has 12 Volts AC **RMS** output. After the bridge rectifier and the reservoir capacitor, the DC output is around `1.41 x 12 - (2 x 0.7)` = ~ **15.52 Volts** at peak. With a suitably large capacitor for the envisaged load, it will happily work with a 7812 as long as ripple doesn't drop the voltage much below 14 Volts.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh Yes, I'm aware that the transformer rating is RMS. At the peak voltage the 12V transformer will just barely exceed the dropout voltage of a typical 7812 regulator. The peak current during that short period of time must be much larger than the desired average current, requiring a higher current rating for the transformer and, as you pointed out, a suitably large capacitor. We also don't have much margin for lower than expected mains voltage, for design tolerances in the transformer, or for temperature effects in the diodes or regulator.

Comment: @JoeHass What voltage headroom do your *typical* 7812 regulators need? ... And how much line undervoltage are you anticipating?